# How to force LaTeX to treat a page with an even page-number as a right-hand page?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

I am writing a document using `\documentclass{book}`, and I need Latex to treat a single even page as a right-hand page (I know, I know), with all the consequences this entails, i.e. page number on the right side, inner margin on the left side etc. The other pages of the document must be unaffected by this change.

My first instinct was to use `\addtocounter{page}{-1} \cleardoublepage` in order to force a right hand side and subtract the page counter. However, this does not work, as LaTeX counts back to the next **odd** number, instead of simply subtracting one in order to count back to an even number.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: I also need the page number to stay the same, so adding blank pages doesn't work.

Edit2: MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \Large{Titlepage}    
\end{center}
\newpage

Abstract goes here
\end{document}
```

The goal is to get the Abstract page to retain page number 2, while being treated as a right-hand page.

Comment: Just to be clear, all the other even pages should still be treated as left hand pages, correct?

Comment: Yes, only a single page should be treated inversely, all other pages should be treated normally.

Comment: You did not tell us why you need it, but: Consider the possibility of building the document with a disposable first page, then deleting that page outside TeX, with one of those PDF editor programs. (perhaps xpdf, qpdf, or something in that concept).

Comment: Unfortunately these work-arounds don't work, because I also need the page number to stay the same. I'll add that detail to my question!

Comment: A titlepage environment will take care of some of it.  For a single page one can change the margins using a minipage shifted by `\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin`.

Comment: The page in question contains the abstract, so a title-page environment doesn't work as well, unfortunately. Thanks for `\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin`, though!

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you have tried to solve it. As it is we have no idea what you have really done.

Comment: I added a MWE just now

Comment: tl;dr: `\makeatletter\@twosidefalse\makeatother` and then undo the change a bit later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want this as a right side page is beyond me, but this will work.  `\thepage` is used by `\label` and the `TOC`, but does not affect the odd/even test.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}% always odd page
\begin{center}
  \Large{Titlepage}    
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{2}% will also change \label and TOC
Abstract goes here
\newpage
\stepcounter{page}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
Resume page 3.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works